# always appear hang in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu

I have **window xp** in my **C drive**. Then I try to install in **Ubuntu 12.10**. In installation process, I choose  `ext4 extending ...` when appear `something else` and other option. Is that wrong?? After completing installation, my computer is going to very much slow and always appear to hang. My processor is Intel Duel-core 2.5, Twin mos 1GB Ram, 250 GB Hard Disk, default video card.

Please help me.

Comment: Hang on. Where is the problem?  Is it with installation or with performance?  Both can be covered by Ubuntu's forums. (Super User, not so much.)

Answer (score 2):

The way your hard disk is formatted should not matter. At least you should choose ext3 or ext4 for installing ubuntu (also FAT32 is possible, but i would prefer ext formating). There might be a problem with your video card driver. Since you did not specify which card you use, i would recommend you to install either the "fglrx" driver for a radeon card or the "nvidia" driver.  Most packages (here i.e. fglrx) you can easily find by typing

```
apt-cache search fglrx
```

in your terminal and install it with

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Beside this your PC seems to fit the requirements for Ubuntu. Maybe you are also booting always your Live CD. Take it out of your DVD or CD ROM drive after Ubuntu has been installed on your hard drive! This would explain why the start is so slowly and the OS "hangs" several times, because it has to access the DVD drive all the time.